# How to hide taskbar in flutter windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, desktop

is there a way to hide windows desktop in Flutter windows. [PS. I am Beginner in flutter]

```
   await WindowManager.instance.setFullScreen(true);
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```

tried the above code but it was hiding the title bar only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager)
For code, you can use this snippet before running the app in main.dart.

```
void main() {
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    await windowManager.ensureInitialized();
    WindowOptions windowOptions = const WindowOptions(
      fullScreen: true,
      skipTaskbar: true,
      center: true,
      size: Size(Constants.verticalW, Constants.verticalH),
      alwaysOnTop: true, // This hide the taskbar and appear the app on top
      titleBarStyle: TitleBarStyle.hidden,
    );
    windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow(windowOptions, () async {
      await windowManager.show();
      await windowManager.focus();
    });
  }

  runApp(const app());
}
```